# File Input Disappearing on Struts Invalid Form Reload

Tags: validation, jsp, file-upload, struts

I have the following in my Struts `ActionForm`

```
private List<FormFile> attachmentList = new ArrayList<FormFile>();

public MyForm() {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
        getAttachmentList().add(null);
    }
}

public List<FormFile> getAttachmentList() {
    return attachmentList;
}

public void setAttachmentList(List<FormFile> attachmentList) {
    this.attachmentList = attachmentList;
}

public FormFile getAttachmentList(int index) {
    return getAttachmentList().get(index);
}

public void setAttachmentList(int index, FormFile formFile) {
    getAttachmentList().set(index, formFile);
}
```

And in my JSP I have the following

```
<c:forEach var="counter" begin="0" end="4">
    <input type="file" name="attachmentList[${counter}]" size="50" />
</c:forEach>
```

Everything works fine, unless the `validate` method of the `ActionForm` finds errors (usually related to other fields on the form). When the form reloads, the file inputs are no longer populated. I added an assert right before the display `Action` returns the reloaded page, and the `ActionForm` has the right number of attachments (their file names are not blank etc).

Does anyone know how to make the files bind and stay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File fields cannot be pre-filled; this is a well-known browser thing and has nothing to do with Struts.